# Discounting the simple things...

Tags: sound-design, learning, methodology

As i'm sitting here fussing with a sfx for what will be a .5 second timed effect, I have settled around a convolved quick little bandpass filter sweep (theeuuuu). I also wondered why i didn't just try this earlier.

As sound designers, we have thousands of tools and methods and options at our disposal, what are some of the bread and butter things that you always end up settling on, and then slapping yourself in the forehead for originally discounting?

Should be fun. Mine are probably sampling and filtered noise, especially for short fx. What are yours?

Answer (score 2):

On one project I wanted some howling wind fx......spent weeks trying to record and nothing was working.  In frustration one day I went into the studio with a mic and spent twenty minutes blowing and howling....I'm sure I don't have to tell you what made it into the final cut.

Comment: good one! that is a great example

Answer (score 2):

Using stock sounds, because they're cheap and (often, sometimes) better what one could've possibly got otherwise.

Comment: yea definitely. Trying to get people to keep these coming, it's funny but could actually be very informative!